# conda: ERROR requests.packages.urllib3.connection:_match_hostname(360): Certificate did not match expected hostname: conda.binstar.org

Tags: anaconda

my anaconda doesn't work any more:

by type in

```
conda install pandas
```

get

```
    Fetching package metadata ...ERROR requests.packages.urllib3.connection:_match_hostname(360): Certificate did not match expected hostname: conda.binstar.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'anaconda.com'),),), 'subjectAltName': [('DNS', 'anaconda.com'), ('DNS', 'anacondacloud.com'), ('DNS', 'anacondacloud.org'), ('DNS', 'binstar.org'), ('DNS', 'wakari.io')]}

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.binstar.org/ottogroup/osx-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'conda.binstar.org' doesn't match either of 'anaconda.com', 'anacondacloud.com', 'anacondacloud.org', 'binstar.org', 'wakari.io'",),),)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (mac os 10.12.4 and conda version 4.3.22). I executed

```
CONDA_SSL_VERIFY=false conda update conda requests pyopenssl cryptography
```

as recommended at [Conda HTTP Error hostname doesn't match #5170](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5170) and it solved the problem. Any conda command I then tried worked fine (i.e., `conda update conda`, `conda create -n py3test python=3 anaconda`, etc.).

Comment: Disabling SSL verification sounds like an bad idea (i.e. unsafe).